# How to make overlaping tabs in tablayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am doing using TabLayout to create tabs. I am trying to achieve the following look

[image]

Here is my code

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/mTabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:background="@drawable/map_tab_layout_bg"
                app:tabBackground="@drawable/map_tab_selector"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MapTabTextAppearance"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabRippleColor="@null"
                app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
                app:tabPaddingStart="0dp" />
```

The selector I have is essentially for button that have the following look

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid
        android:color="#111111"/>
    <corners android:radius="25dp"/>


</shape>
```

However I am getting the tabs similar to this

[image]

Basically rounded buttons beside each other. How can I achieve the format I desire?

Thank you